# Using package.json dependencies as folderstructure in gulpfile.js

Tags: gulp, node-modules, package.json, gulp-sass

I'm trying to create an automated process for including node modules in my projects. Some modules have css included, and so I'm trying to make gulpfile.js in a way it can read those modules and include the css of that module.

I try to be selective and have only the folders selected that I install as a dependency. Not the entire node_modules folder.

My gulpfile.js:

```
// Import (not showing all for the sake of the question)
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const fs = require('fs');
const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));

// File paths
const files = { 
    cssPath: 'assets/styles/**/*.scss',
    jsPath: 'assets/scripts/**/*.js',
    imgPath: 'assets/images/**/*',
    modulesPath: ['node_modules']+json.dependencies+'/**/*.scss'
    //Desired output: node_modules/module_name/all_folders/all.scss
}

// Compile CSS
function styles(){
    return src([files.cssPath, files.modulesPath])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(dest('dist/styles')
    );
}
```

When I run "gulp styles" the function runs just fine, but the desired styles are not included. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's an easier way to get your `package.json` file:

```js
const package = require('./package.json');
```

Then you need the names of your dependencies, which are the keys in the `dependencies` object. Map these to a glob, like this:

```js
const files = {
  ...
  modulesPath: Object.keys(package.dependencies).map(module => `node_modules/${module}/**/*.scss`)
}
```

Lastly, destructure that array in your `styles` task:

```js
return src([files.cssPath, ...files.modulesPath])
```